# Issues with MKPolyline

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkpolyline

I am very new to Xcode and I am facing issues in tracing user path using polyline.

I am getting locations correctly. I am able to add pins properly. However, my polyline method is never called.

Below is my code.

In header file...

```
@interface Tracker : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    MKMapView *mapView;
    //other declarations
}
```

Inside implementation file, I have following code. I call, drawPolyline method inside didUpdateLocations method, which is called correctly.

```
- (void) drawPolyline:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSInteger numberOfLocations = [locations count];
    if (numberOfLocations > 1)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D *locationCoordinate2DArray = malloc(numberOfLocations * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLocations; i++)
        {
            CLLocation* current = [locations objectAtIndex:i];
            locationCoordinate2DArray[i] = current.coordinate;
        }

        self.polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:locationCoordinate2DArray count:numberOfLocations];
        free(locationCoordinate2DArray);

        [mapView addOverlay:self.polyline];
        [mapView setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

- (MKOverlayView*)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView* polyLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.polyline];
    polyLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    polyLineView.lineWidth = 2;
    return polyLineView;
}
```

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapView:viewForOverlay:` is a delegate method, so you'll need to set the mapview's delegate somewhere. Otherwise, the delegate method will never be called.

```
[mapView setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The real issue was my logic - if (numberOfLocations > 1). It looks like numberOfLocations increases only if I move at least 200 feet. I commented that line and now viewForOverlay is called. However, the performance is bad. Map is flickering. I can avoid the issue by using MKPointAnnotation. However, this gives me a pin. Is there a way to replace the pin with a dot or another image?

Comment: You can create a dot image yourself and return it. Check the MapCallouts sample code from Apple for an example.